# Any way to set password on BIOS remotely on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, remote, bios

I maintain many specific-use devices that have Ubuntu 14.04 OS installed on them.  There is an ongoing effort on our end to harden the security on these devices.  One of the required steps is setting a password on BIOS.  Anyway to do this remotely?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say you'll need to access their DRAC/ILO/IPMI interfaces and when rebooting the machine you can enter the BIOS and set the password.

Comment: Pretend I know nothing (I really don't) about Ubuntu.  How do I even start?  I assume figuring out which interface the device use and then searching for ways to access it?  I'm not sure how to begin.  Thanks for your tip

Comment: DRAC / ILO / IPMI are out-of-band management interfaces on the physical server. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Assuming someone configured an IP address on them when initially installing and configuring the servers, you can access this OOB management interface either via a web interface from your client or perhaps via SSH.

Comment: I am afraid this may not be an available option.  The only access we have is root access to the devices themselves.

Comment: They are your physical servers, are they not?

Comment: This is going to depend on the specific hardware.  For Dell PCs, for example, you can use their Command Configure software to set the BIOS password from within the operating system.  But there is unlikely to be any generic solution that works for all hardware.